# Convert Procedure to Function

Tags: c#, meta-programming, rubberduck

My latest inspection for Rubberduck determines whether a procedure should be a function by checking whether it has a single `ByRef` parameter (either explicit or implicit).  The quick fix takes this procedure, changes it into a function, and updates all calls.

This inspection starts deep down, involving the parser:

```
private class ArgListWithOneByRefParamListener : VBABaseListener
{
    private readonly IList<VBAParser.ArgListContext> _contexts = new List<VBAParser.ArgListContext>();
    public IEnumerable<VBAParser.ArgListContext> Contexts { get { return _contexts; } }

    public override void ExitArgList(VBAParser.ArgListContext context)
    {
        if (context.arg() != null && context.arg().Count(a => a.BYREF() != null || (a.BYREF() == null && a.BYVAL() == null)) == 1)
        {
            _contexts.Add(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we have a method that listens for any `ArgList`s and determines whether they have a single `ByRef` parameter.  If so, it adds the `ArgListContext` to a list exposed through the parser state class.

Here is the inspection:

```
public class ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspection : IInspection
{
    public ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspection()
    {
        Severity = CodeInspectionSeverity.Warning;
    }

    public string Name { get { return "ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspection"; } }
    public string Meta { get { return InspectionsUI.ResourceManager.GetString(Name + "Meta"); } }
    public string Description { get { return InspectionsUI.ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspection; } }
    public CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get { return CodeInspectionType.LanguageOpportunities; } }
    public CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults(RubberduckParserState state)
    {
        return state.ArgListsWithOneByRefParam
            .Where(context => context.Context.Parent is VBAParser.SubStmtContext)
            .Select(context => new ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspectionResult(this,
                state,
                new QualifiedContext<VBAParser.ArgListContext>(context.ModuleName,
                    context.Context as VBAParser.ArgListContext),
                new QualifiedContext<VBAParser.SubStmtContext>(context.ModuleName,
                    context.Context.Parent as VBAParser.SubStmtContext)));
    }
}
```

That Linq strikes me as a mite messy, but I decided it wasn't that bad.  The alternative is a list and a loop with a few intermediate variables.  If you think it is worth it, just let me know.  Here, I determine whether the `ArgListContext`s `Parent` is a `SubStmtContext`.  If it is not, this inspection does not apply.  If it is, I deliver both the `ArgListContext` and its `SubStmtContext` parent to the inspection result:

```
public class ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspectionResult : CodeInspectionResultBase
{
   private readonly IEnumerable<CodeInspectionQuickFix> _quickFixes;

   public ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspectionResult(IInspection inspection, RubberduckParserState state, QualifiedContext<VBAParser.ArgListContext> argListQualifiedContext, QualifiedContext<VBAParser.SubStmtContext> subStmtQualifiedContext)
       : base(inspection,
            string.Format(inspection.Description, subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.ambiguousIdentifier().GetText()),
            subStmtQualifiedContext.ModuleName,
            subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.ambiguousIdentifier())
    {
        _quickFixes = new[]
        {
            new ChangeProcedureToFunction(state, argListQualifiedContext, subStmtQualifiedContext, QualifiedSelection), 
        };
    }

    public override IEnumerable<CodeInspectionQuickFix> QuickFixes { get { return _quickFixes; } }
}
```

Here, I create the custom text for the inspection result and register a code fix.  I'm not sure whether I should DI the parent `SubStmtContext` here, or just call `context.Parent` here.  Opinions welcome.

This is the quick fix:

```
public class ChangeProcedureToFunction : CodeInspectionQuickFix
{
    public override bool CanFixInModule { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanFixInProject { get { return false; } }

    private readonly RubberduckParserState _state;
    private readonly QualifiedContext<VBAParser.ArgListContext> _argListQualifiedContext;
    private readonly QualifiedContext<VBAParser.SubStmtContext> _subStmtQualifiedContext;
    private readonly QualifiedContext<VBAParser.ArgContext> _argQualifiedContext;

    private int _lineOffset;

    public ChangeProcedureToFunction(RubberduckParserState state,
                                     QualifiedContext<VBAParser.ArgListContext> argListQualifiedContext,
                                     QualifiedContext<VBAParser.SubStmtContext> subStmtQualifiedContext,
                                     QualifiedSelection selection)
        : base(subStmtQualifiedContext.Context, selection, InspectionsUI.ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspectionQuickFix)
    {
        _state = state;
        _argListQualifiedContext = argListQualifiedContext;
        _subStmtQualifiedContext = subStmtQualifiedContext;
        _argQualifiedContext = new QualifiedContext<VBAParser.ArgContext>(_argListQualifiedContext.ModuleName,
            _argListQualifiedContext.Context.arg()
                .First(a => a.BYREF() != null || (a.BYREF() == null && a.BYVAL() == null)));
    }

    public override void Fix()
    {
        UpdateSignature();
        UpdateCalls();
    }

    private void UpdateSignature()
    {
        var argListText = _argListQualifiedContext.Context.GetText();
        var subStmtText = _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.GetText();
        var argText = _argQualifiedContext.Context.GetText();

        var newArgText = argText.Contains("ByRef ") ? argText.Replace("ByRef ", "ByVal ") : "ByVal " + argText;

        var newFunctionWithoutReturn = subStmtText.Insert(subStmtText.IndexOf(argListText, StringComparison.Ordinal) + argListText.Length,
                                                          _argQualifiedContext.Context.asTypeClause().GetText())
                                                  .Replace("Sub", "Function")
                                                  .Replace(argText, newArgText);

        var newfunctionWithReturn = newFunctionWithoutReturn
            .Insert(newFunctionWithoutReturn.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine, StringComparison.Ordinal),
                    Environment.NewLine + "    " + _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.ambiguousIdentifier().GetText() +
                    " = " + _argQualifiedContext.Context.ambiguousIdentifier().GetText());

        _lineOffset = newfunctionWithReturn.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length -
                     subStmtText.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length;

        var module = _argListQualifiedContext.ModuleName.Component.CodeModule;

        module.DeleteLines(_subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.Start.Line,
            _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.Stop.Line - _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.Start.Line + 1);
        module.InsertLines(_subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.Start.Line, newfunctionWithReturn);
    }

    private void UpdateCalls()
    {
        var procedureName = _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.ambiguousIdentifier().GetText();

        var procedure =
            _state.AllDeclarations.SingleOrDefault(d =>
                    !d.IsBuiltIn &&
                    d.IdentifierName == procedureName &&
                    d.Context is VBAParser.SubStmtContext &&
                    d.ComponentName == _subStmtQualifiedContext.ModuleName.ComponentName &&
                    d.Project == _subStmtQualifiedContext.ModuleName.Project);

        if (procedure == null) { return; }

        foreach (var reference in procedure.References.OrderByDescending(o => o.Selection.StartLine).ThenByDescending(d => d.Selection.StartColumn))
        {
            var startLine = reference.Selection.StartLine;

            if (procedure.ComponentName == reference.QualifiedModuleName.ComponentName && procedure.Selection.EndLine < reference.Selection.StartLine)
            {
                startLine += _lineOffset;
            }

            var module = reference.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;

            var referenceParent = reference.Context.Parent as VBAParser.ICS_B_ProcedureCallContext;
            if (referenceParent == null) { continue; }

            var referenceText = reference.Context.Parent.GetText();
            var newCall = referenceParent.argsCall().argCall().ToList().ElementAt(_argListQualifiedContext.Context.arg().ToList().IndexOf(_argQualifiedContext.Context)).GetText() +
                          " = " + _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.ambiguousIdentifier().GetText() +
                          "(" + referenceParent.argsCall().GetText() + ")";

            var oldLines = module.Lines[startLine, reference.Selection.LineCount];

            var newText = oldLines.Remove(reference.Selection.StartColumn - 1, referenceText.Length)
                .Insert(reference.Selection.StartColumn - 1, newCall);

            module.DeleteLines(startLine, reference.Selection.LineCount);
            module.InsertLines(startLine, newText);
        }
    }
}
```

This converts the procedure into a function like this:

> ```
> Private Sub foo(ByRef bar As Integer)
> End Sub
> ```

> ```
> Private Function foo(ByVal bar as Integer) As Integer
>     foo = bar
> End Function
> ```

Calls, such as:

> ```
> Dim biz As Integer
> biz = 9
> foo biz
> ```

Are turned into:

> ```
> biz = foo(9)
> ```

This looks just a bit messy in places.  Am I missing some ways to clean it up?

P.S.  The owner of Rubberduck says to use `var` (and it is pretty obvious what things are once you know the project internals :P), so you needn't comment on that.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, so if it already behaves this way, I apologize. IMO, the inspection should only trigger if the sub is passed a param ByRef *and* the param then has its value set from inside the sub.

Comment: @RubberDuck I did not check this, but it should be easy to determine and refine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This condition `a.BYREF() != null || (a.BYREF() == null && a.BYVAL() == null)` can be simplified to `a.BYREF() != null || a.BYVAL() == null` since if `BYREF` is not unequal to `null` then it is equal to `null`.

   Also this logic is repeated again in another class - this violates DRY. It should be a method on the `ArgContext` (if I got the type right).
2. In `ProcedureShouldBeFunctionInspection` some properties reference the `InspectionUI` - it seems odd that an engine style class has a reference to the UI but there might be perfectly good reasons for it. Just seems a bit suspicious so I mentioned it.
3. In `GetInspectionResults` you use `as` in several places. Would it make sense for those casts to return `null`? Can the constructed objects deal with those parameters being `null`? If not then you should use a direct cast instead.
4. This:

   > ```
   >     _lineOffset = newfunctionWithReturn.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length -
   >              subStmtText.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length;
   > ```

   seems sufficiently ugly to warrant a `string` extension method (especially since I would suspect you might do this in other parts of your project):

   ```
   public static IList<string> SplitLines(this string s)
   {
       return s.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
   }
   ```

   which would translate the above code into:

   ```
   _lineOffset = newfunctionWithReturn.SplitLines().Count -
                subStmtText.SplitLines().Count;
   ```
5. Extracting sub expressions with multiple uses into a local variable can help to improve readability. Like this:

   ```
   var startLine = _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.Start.Line;
   var stopLine =  _subStmtQualifiedContext.Context.Stop.Line;

   module.DeleteLines(startLine, stopLine - startLine + 1);
   module.InsertLines(startLine, newfunctionWithReturn);
   ```
6. `referenceParent.argsCall().argCall().ToList().ElementAt(_argListQualifiedContext.Context.arg().ToList().IndexOf(_argQualifiedContext.Context)).GetText()` - Seriously?
7. I think I've mentioned it in a previous review, but I'll repeat it again: You have call chains 3 or 4 items deep on a regular basis - this indicates that the abstractions are probably not quite right.

Comment: I can't touch the parse tree.  Essentially, I am digging around in a tree to get the parent and child items in most of these really long calls, including the one mentioned in point 6).  I will split that one into a couple statements, but it will really boil down to the same line, only easier to read.